# Ошибка при попытки создании таблицы PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
 create table delivery(
        delivery_id serial primary key,
        address_id int references address(address_id) not null, 
        delivery_date date not null, 
        time_range text[] not null, 
        staff_id int references staff(staff_id) not null, 
        status del_status not null default 'в обработке', 
        last_update timestamp, 
        create_date timestamp default now(),
        deleted boolean not null default false
    )

select * from delivery
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: Ну там написано что недостаточно прав, значит оно так и есть. Зайдите под пользователем под которым создавали таблицу address или выдайте себе полные права на нее

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет таблицы address на которую вы ссылаетесь в третьей строке. Чтобы код работал нужно скачать дамп учебной базы данных. Для этого нужно выполнить 7-ой пункт [в этой инструкции](https://github.com/netology-ds-team/sql-materials/tree/main/sqlfree).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)